# 'maxValue' must be greater than zero

Tags: c#

I'm not sure it's an issue, but something looks like *not correct* in the message.

My first try:

```
try
{
    var r = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine(r.Next(-1));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType().ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Output:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>
> 'maxValue' must be greater than zero.
>
> Parameter name: maxValue

My second try:

```
try
{
    var r = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine(r.Next(0));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType().ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Output:

> 0

So, the *problem* is: why is `0` **greater than zero**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,8aeb183c03bdcdcf,references):

```
  /*=====================================Next=====================================
  **Returns: An int [0..maxValue)
  **Arguments: maxValue -- One more than the greatest legal return value.
  **Exceptions: None.
  ==============================================================================*/
  public virtual int Next(int maxValue) {
      if (maxValue<0) {
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxValue", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_MustBePositive", "maxValue"));
      }
      Contract.EndContractBlock();
      return (int)(Sample()*maxValue);
  }
```

The value must be positive and zero is positive.

Comment: How can 0 be positive? 0 is neither positive nor negative! 0 is 0!

Answer (score 1):

By definition from MSDN [Random.Next Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx).

> maxValue Type: 
>   System.Int32 The exclusive upper bound of the random
>   number to be generated. maxValue must be greater than or equal to 0.

So yes we can say that the error message is misleading. It should be greater than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

[Random.Next Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **maxValue:** The exclusive upper bound of the random number to be generated. maxValue must be greater than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Parameters**

```
maxValue
```

Type: `System.Int32`
The exclusive upper bound of the random number to be generated. maxValue must be greater than or equal to 0.

From [Random.Next Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The value cant be negative.zero or above is acceptable.That's why your are getting above answer.